# Mixing 12/2 and 14/2 house wiring

Tags: wiring

Can I run 12/2 wiring from a load center to a junction box, then use 14/2 for branch circuits?

Comment: Never a good idea to do this.  Maybe if you ran out of the one size of wire.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this to begin with?

Comment: The only reason I would consider this is to minimize voltage drop for a long run on a lighting-only circuit. Doing lighting circuits entirely in 12 awg is unnecessary in the age of LED lighting while increasing cost (more expensive wire, larger junction boxes) and 14 awg is much easier to work with at the fixtures and switch boxes. Definitely make sure to leave a note at the panel though.

Comment: @ statueuphemism Why lighting only? It would seem your LED reasoning reduces the need to increase size to compensate for voltage drop, while receptacles would be prone to overload.

Comment: I seriously  doubt you'll have voltage drop problems with #14 AWG. Just how many miles is this run you're talking about?

Comment: @JACK While it may be a minority opinion, some view any unnecessary voltage drop as a problem due to the energy waste, not just if the lights flicker or an appliance misbehaves.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease You're right that it applies to any 15 A circuit and even more-so to general purpose receptacles. For me personally, I would only use 14 awg on a lighting circuit (or some other known loads like a security camera or hardwired smoke detectors). Anything with a general purpose receptacle on it gets at least 12 awg in my house.

Comment: The  problem I have is All of the front rm and one bedroom share a 15 amp circuit with a total of 8 outlets and 3 lights. Since I have lots of space in the breaker box I want to separate the bedroom feed (4 outlets; 2 lights). I'd like to run 12 ga to a junction box above bedroom and tie outlets/lights to this as a new circuit. If I can't pull the old wire (cloth type cover/unsure of gauge) thru walls I'll have to tie them into newly pulled line. The few electricians Ive talked to say they usually just pull 12ga nowadays. Run from breaker box to center of bedroom would be 30-40 ft.

Answer (score 8):

You can, but **only** if the breaker is **15 amps**, and it creates possible confusion for someone who looks at the breaker box and thinks "huh, that's 12GA, I can change that to a 20A breaker." So you might want to leave that person a note in the box.

Answer (score 2):

### You may be miscalculating voltage drop

The first rule of voltage drop is:  Calculate voltage drop based on the *actual, normal circuit load, not breaker trip*.  Suppose  you have 7A of lighting, but only 3A will be realistically on at one time, on a 15A trip.  What number do you punch into the voltage drop calc?

> 3 amps.  The *normal* load.

The second rule of voltage drop is: 3% is nonsense - nothing in Code even talks about this. 3.000% is super nonsense.  Most of the voltage drop calculators online will consider 3.001% voltage drop to be *condemning*, and will force you into a larger wire size at that point.  That is patently absurd.  If the calc reveals a 3.5% drop, that is unquestionably fine.  Larger drops are a judgment call, but they're your judgment call.  Some loads these days are 100-264V voltage-flexible, so you can tolerate a LOT of drop, especially on a 240V circuit, which can be awesome for pole lights on farms.    So suppose you are wiring a pole light that takes 100-240V.  120V voltage drop calculates at 7%.  Is that OK?

> Yes.

### If #12 is used in a 15A circuit, *mark, mark, mark*.

For instance now that Romex is color coded, bring about 2" of Romex jacket into the box, and overtape the visible yellow jacket with white tape - to make clear it is #14.  Otherwise it will be too tempting to put a 20A breaker there. Mark the hot wire with a tag and write #14 wire on it.

Comment: Why is 3% nonsense? Voltage drop = energy wasted in transmission. A 7% voltage drop on a 12 A resistive load like a space heater is ~100W just being lost to the wires in your walls and not being used to heat the space you want to heat. It makes more sense to me to take a one-time hit on increased cost of wire to minimize recurring costs (and be environmentally friendly if you're into that sort of thing) due to unnecessary voltage drop.

Comment: @statueuphemism Fair enough, and I changed my example. My point is we ought to make a considered decision ourselves instead of blindly doing what the wire salesman says.  The *usual* case I see is someone spending $600 extra to avert 50 cents a month worth of transmission losses to occasional-use tools in a shed.